# Entities passed to the choice field must be managed

Tags: php, symfony

I create a new object and bind it to a form.  The user fills out the form and goes to a preview page.  I store the user responses in the session.

The problem crops up when I try to reload the object from the session when the user goes back to edit the form.  I get :

> Error: the Entities passed to the choice field must be managed.

Anyone have an idea of where i might be going wrong?  Heres the code for the controllers.

```
public function previewdealAction(Request $request){

    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $coupon = $session->get('coupon');
    $form = $this->createForm(new CouponType(), $coupon);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

        //bind the posted form values
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        //once a valid form is submitted ...
        if ($form->isValid()){
           //Proceed to Previewing deal
            $file = $coupon->getImage();
            $file->upload();
            $session->set('coupon', $coupon);

            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('FrontendUserBundle:Coupon');
            $coupons = $repository->findAll();

            return $this->render('FrontendHomeBundle:Merchant:dealpreview.html.twig', array('coupon'=>$coupon, 'coupons'=>$coupons));

        }
    }

}
public function builddealAction(Request $request){

    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    //check for a coupon session variable
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

    $coupon = $session->get('coupon');

    //If coupon is not set
    if($coupon == NULL){
        $coupon = new Coupon();
        $date = new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $coupon->setStartdate($date);
        $coupon->setPosterid($user);
        $session->set('coupon', $coupon);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new CouponType(), $coupon);
    return $this->render('FrontendHomeBundle:Merchant:builddeal.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

--

```
namespace Frontend\HomeBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class CouponType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('couponname', 'text');
    $builder->add('description', 'textarea');
    $builder->add('price', 'money', array('currency' => 'USD'));
    $builder->add('originalprice', 'money', array('currency' => 'USD'));
    $builder->add('maxlimit', 'integer');
    $builder->add('maxper', 'integer');
    $builder->add('startdate', 'date', array(
        'years' => array(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),

    ));
    $builder->add('duration', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => array(
            '3'   => 3,
            '7'   => 7,
            '14' => 14,
            '30'   => 30,
            '60'   => 60,
            '90'   => 90,
            ),
        'expanded'  => false,
        'multiple'  => false,
        ));
    $builder->add('expirationdate', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => array(
            '30'   => 30,
            '60'   => 60,
            '90' => 90,
            '180'   => 180,
            ),
        'expanded'  => false,
        'multiple'  => false,
        ));
    $builder->add('tip', 'integer');
    $builder->add('salestax', 'choice', array(
       'choices'   => array(
            'included'   => 'Sales tax is included and will be remitted BY YOU at the appropriate tax jurisdiction',
            'exempt'   => 'Sales tax is exempt according to seller\'s tax jurisdiction',
            'collected' => 'Sales tax will be collected BY YOU at time of deal redemption',
            ),
        'expanded'  => true,
        'multiple'  => false,
    ));
    $builder->add('signature', 'text');
    $builder->add('city', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Frontend\\UserBundle\\Entity\\Cities',
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,

    ));
    $builder->add('category', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Frontend\\UserBundle\\Entity\\Category',
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
    ));
    $builder->add('address', new AddressType());
    $builder->add('image', new DocumentType());
    $builder->add('maxper', 'choice', array(
        'choices'   => array(
            '1'   => 1,
            '2'   => 2,
            '3' => 3,
            '4'   => 4,
            '5'   => 5,
            '6'   => 6,
            '7' => 7,
            '8'   => 8,
            '9'   => 9,
            '10'   => 10,
            ),
        'expanded'  => false,
        'multiple'  => false,
        ));

}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Frontend\UserBundle\Entity\Coupon',
    );
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}

}
```

heres the coupon type class

Comment: Can you add your CouponType Class?

Comment: What kind of relationship is there between coupon and category?

Comment: max per is just an integer field in the coupon entity.

Comment: the main offending fields seem to be the city and category. but it's weird, it only throws an error if I'm loading the coupon entity from the session, not if its a new Coupon();

Comment: mmm one second lemme check the relationship.. i believe they are both manytoone

Comment: when i was looking around it said it might help to add cascades to them but i dont see how that would help anything

Comment: Do you have any many to many relationships? That's where I've always seen this particular error.

Comment: mmm... theres no many to many relationships in the coupon class.

Comment: Are you aware that you define maxper twice?  That's not causing the error, but it is happening.

Comment: ah i didn't notice that, thanks

Comment: Okay.. so I'm pretty positive it was a problem with moving the object across the session...  I'm trying to use the entity manager instead of the session.  The only problem I'm having is that I dont have an identifier to retrieve the object between pages until I flush.  Is there a way to retrieve it without flushing?  I'd prefer not to put it in the database until all the information on it is finalized.

Comment: Did you even find a solution to this? I'm experiencing a similar issue, using `FormBuilder::setData()` which I've pulled from a posted Form and stored in the session.

Answer (score 29):

I was experiencing the same problem - I was retrieving data from a form using `getData()` and storing in the session. Later on, after a redirect, I was attempting to repopulate another instance of the same form using `setData()`.

I experienced no issues with native fields. However, when my form included an entity I was receiving the same dreaded message "Entities passed to the choice field must be managed".

After some head scratching the issue revealed itself to be pretty straightforward (aren't they all?). After a redirect, the entity has become detached; the solution is simply to re-include the entity into the EntityManager using `EntityManager::merge()`, thus reinstating the entity as a managed object :)

```
// an array of form data from session
$entity = $data['my_entity'];

// merge() returns the managed entity
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->merge($entity);

// update the form data array
$data['my_entity'] = $entity;

// Create form with form data 
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $data);
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/doctrine/orm/entitymanager.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a massive help, solved my problem of storing entities in a session. I was getting this error via a "Can not read the choices from the choice list" (currently 0 results on Google) through trying to populate a fields in a formType with selected values - hopefully this comment will help others find this answer.

Comment: I had similar issue - when keeping the data in simple cache - and this solved it!  Just had to take care and actually do something like `$agent = $em->merge($agent);` and not just `$em->merge($agent);`. Thanks!

Comment: Although - the point of caching is lost when you need to do too much re-merging into EM, because it's too slow.

Comment: Thanks, though the merge function is deprecated now, but still works.

Comment: Thanks @Faizan — haven't used Doctrine in a while. Do you know what it's going to be replaced by?

Answer (score 14):

It's not relating to solve your specific problem but I'd like to annotate: 
I've had the same problem and could solve it by **removing** `'by_reference' => false` which was needless here and the reason for this error.

Comment: Thanks. I've eagerly added `'by_reference' => false` to all my relations. However only collections actually need this.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem and used pretty much the answer Daggah supposed, but added a small loop through the array of entities, checking for objects:

```
if ($this->get('session')->has('filters')) {
    $filters = $this->get('session')->get('filters');
    foreach ($filters as $key => $filter) {
        if (is_object($filter)) {
            $filters[$key] = $em->merge($filter);
        }
    }
    $filterForm = $this->createForm(new FilterType(), $filters);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the loop with my arrayCollection and it worked perfectly !

Comment: Excellent !!! And if **$filters** is not an array but an object, just replace `$filters[$key]` line 5 by `filter->$key` (your keys must be public)

Comment: Working fine except with DateTime objects, getting error `The class 'DateTime' was not found in the chain configured namespaces` any idea why ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and both answers were very helpful, but my issue involved multidimensional arrays so to keep things dynamic I used a recursive version of jahller's function.

```
private function manageObjects(&$data_array)
{
    foreach ($data_array as $key => &$value)
        if (is_object($value))
            $data_array[$key] = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->merge($value);
        else if (is_array($value))
            $this->manageObjects($value);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: The recursive function does not seems to work, it gives me : Class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection is not a valid entity or mapped super class. But if I do this by hand like here : http://pastie.org/private/h082ucbyw6sz7dyym3avtq it works.

Answer (score 0):

More complex solution basing on prev comments.
Support ArrayCollections and DateTime objects

```
 /**
 * Merge objects
 * Allow to manage object by doctrine when using stored (eg. in session data values)
 * @param $data_array - list of form fields
 * @return mixed
 */
public function manageObjects($data_array)
{
    foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {
        // for multi choices
        if ($value instanceof ArrayCollection) {
            $data_array[$key] = $this->manageObjects($value);
        } 
        //ommit dateTime object
        elseif ($value instanceof \DateTime) {

        } 
        elseif (is_object($value)) {
            $data_array[$key] = $this->getService('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->merge($value);
        }
    }
    return $data_array;
}
```