# How to relate two input field in a symfony 3 form

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

Please how can I achieve this.i have two choice fields(entity) such as category and skills. I want the  skills field to be dependent on category i.e if a category is selected the options of the skill should be the skills related to that category  but if no category is selected, the options of the field should be all the skills.

> NOTE THE CODE BELOW IS JUST FOR ILLUSTRATION PURPOSE

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{


    $builder
        if ( a value is selected from
             (->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'=>'AppBundle:Category',
            'choice_label'=>'name'
             ))) )
        {
                present skills based on the selected category as

                ( ->add('skill', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class'=>'AppBundle:Skill',
                    'choice_label'=>'name',

                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                            ->select('s')
                            ->where('c = :category')
                            ->setParameter('category', $value selected from category);
                    },

                )))
}else{

 ->add('skill', EntityType::class, array(
    'class'=>'AppBundle:skill',
    'choice_label'=>'name'
    ))
```

}

Comment: Many duplicates for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use form event subscribers :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: Thanks its a point in the right direction. after following the instruction i get this error **Entities passed to the choice field must be managed** can you help? the detail of this question is here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473872/entities-passed-to-the-choice-field-must-be-managed]

Comment: where do i use the entity merge