# Symfony error when search filter stored in session

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, session-variables

Let's say I have a Book `Entity` with a ManyToOne relation to `Author` entity.

On a page listing all the books, I have a search Form with a field *'Author'*.
I store the data of my search form in an object (**not en entity**, not persisted) called `searchFilter`.
I made a `SearchFilterType` in which I'm using the **EntityType class** in order to display a choice list of the authors, so one can search all the books with this author.

When I visit another page and then come back to the search page, I want my last search to be remembered, that's why I'm storing the `searchFilter` object in the *session*.

```
$request->getSession()->set('searchFilter', $searchFilter);
```

But when I go back to the search page, I get the error:

`Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?`

**My question**:

Do I have to turn my searchFilter object into an entity in order to persist it, or is there an easier way? I don't want my searchFilter to persist forever, session time would be enough.

## EDIT:

I think my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473872/entities-passed-to-the-choice-field-must-be-managed) where excellent solutions were offered.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions cannot store objects. Therefore you need to serialize and de-serialize your object. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

And see this [simple implementation example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#create-your-user-entity)