# Symfony 4 store entity in session

Tags: php, doctrine, session-variables, symfony4, entities

I have a multi-page form that collects some data and then will be saving it to multiple tables. What is the correct way to save an entity to session in symfony 4?  I see the documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/entities-in-session.html) that states:

> In Doctrine an entity objects has to be "managed" by an EntityManager
>   to be updateable. Entities saved into the session are not managed in
>   the next request anymore. This means that you have to register these
>   entities with an EntityManager again if you want to change them or use
>   them as part of references between other entities. You can achieve
>   this by calling EntityManager#merge().

and

> Entities that are serialized into the session normally contain references to other entities as well. Think of the user entity has a reference to his articles, groups, photos or many other different entities. If you serialize this object into the session then you don't want to serialize the related entities as well. This is why you should call EntityManager#detach() on this object or implement the __sleep() magic method on your entity.

Do I need to do this with symfony? How would I?

Perhaps a better question would be - should I even be using entities with sessions or should I store them in a class and just load all the class information into the entity at the end?

Comment: I was unaware of the documentation you posted, but perhaps not needed with symfony?? For very different reasons than yours, I have a script that creates an entity, makes appropriate links to associated entity records (through ManyToOne relationships), then saves to a session variable. It actually stores an array of entities. Then on next pass I persist each of these in a foreach() loop. I have no problems. Not sure of "official" answer. If helpful I can post some code in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, this can be applicable.

One of the purposes of storing entities in session *-as mentionned in the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/cookbook/entities-in-session.html)-* is "**Multi-step forms**". Using an **Entity** from the session in a **Form** can get you the following error:

> Entity **Your\Entity** passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?

---

You can read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473872/entities-passed-to-the-choice-field-must-be-managed/7931437) about this issue.